# What is big O notation of the following functions?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

So I have few simple functions I wrote and I would like to find out how to calculate their big O notation.

I assume that the big O notaion for the first function is O(log b log a). And for the second one is O(2n). But I believe it can not be that easy and deep analysis has to be involved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to exactly choose operation with respect to which you count complexity. In first if you count divisions, then it is only one, so complexity is $O(1)$.

For second if you choose, for example, multiplication and length of list is $n$ then you can use that $O(2n)=O(n)=O(Cn)$ for any fixed $C>0$.

Comment: why is it $O(2n)=...$?

Comment: It is general property of big-$O$: for $\forall C>0$, $C\cdot O(f(n))=O(C\cdot f(n))=O(f(n))$.

Comment: of course but multiply by the # $2$ does not make it '$O(2n)=...$' IINM each multiply usually counts as 'one.'

Comment: **Of course** $O(2n)=O(n)=O(Cn)$ for any fixed $C>0$ . What is  IINM and from where you take ' IINM each multiply usually counts as 'one.'  ? Make clear, please.

Comment: correct.  IINM is 'if i a not mistaken.'  it is just that for time-complexity of code usually you count the number of a certain operation and in this case i think it is the multiply operation with the multiplicands being arbitrary/irrelevant. big-O is for fxn $f(n)$ $f(n)=O(g(n))$ where exists/for fixed $C$, $f(n)\le Cg(n), n\ge x_0$ as we are concerned here with $n$ tending to infinity.

Comment: so in this case i believe it is $f(n) = O(n)$ as ${1\over{3}}n\le n, n\ge 0$. why is '$\forall{C\gt 0}, CO(f(n))=...$' relevant here?

Comment: Big-$O$ "eats" any constant, regardless of is it more or less then $1$, so, main here is that amount of multiplications linearly depend on list length.

Comment: yeah so?  that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Which question? Big-$O$ "eats" any constant is exactly what is written: $\forall{C\gt 0}, CO(f(n))=...$

Comment: why is '∀C>0,CO(f(n))=...' relevant here? to this code: numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
"""Take a list of numbers and modify it in place by
multiplying every 3rd number by 2."""
def numb(numbers):
    for i in range(2, len(numbers), 3):
        numbers[i] *= 2
    return(numbers)
numb(numbers)

Comment: We come to circle - answer is in my 1-st comment to you. Can you rephrase question?